# How do I use LINQ to group & project objects, based on a member dictionary key?

Tags: c#, list, linq, dictionary

I have a `List<Predictions>` that I would like to project onto a `List<List<PredictionObj>>`. These two classes are defined as follows:

```
public Predictions
{
    public Dictionary<string, double> PredictedMetrics { get; private set; }
    public DateTime PredictionTimeStamp { get; set; }
    public Predictions()
    {
        PredictedMetrics = new Dictionary<string, double>();
    }
}

public class PredictionObj
{
    public string PredictedMetricName { get; set; }
    public double PredictedMetricValue { get; set; }
    public DateTime PredictionTimeStamp { get; set; }
}
```

For context, each `Predictions` object in the `List<Predictions>` list contains a collection (`PredictedMetrics`) of predicted values for a set of metrics, which were made at `PredictionTimeStamp`. I'd like to separate each of those metrics into their own list, such that there will be one list (`List<PredictionObj>`) for every unique `PredictedMetrics` key in the list. (`PredictedMetricName` will map to the dictionary's key, `PredictedMetricValue` will map to the dictionary's value). I'd like to store all of these lists in one `List<List<PredictionObj>>` list.

Is there a way to accomplish this using LINQ extension methods?

You can copy/paste the source below into [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) as an example. I'm looking for LINQ that will accomplish what GenerateSeperateMetricLists is doing:

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime currTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
    List<Predictions> records = new List<Predictions>();
    Predictions record1 = new Predictions();
    record1.PredictedMetrics.Add("metric1", 2.2d);
    record1.PredictedMetrics.Add("metric2", 0.2d);
    record1.PredictionTimeStamp = currTime;
    records.Add(record1);
    Predictions record2 = new Predictions();
    record2.PredictedMetrics.Add("metric1", 1.2d);
    record2.PredictedMetrics.Add("metric2", 0.1d);
    record2.PredictionTimeStamp = currTime.AddMinutes(1);
    records.Add(record2);
    Predictions record3 = new Predictions();
    record3.PredictedMetrics.Add("metric1", 3.2d);
    record3.PredictedMetrics.Add("metric2", 0.3d);
    record3.PredictionTimeStamp = currTime.AddMinutes(2);
    records.Add(record3);
    Predictions record4 = new Predictions();
    record4.PredictedMetrics.Add("metric1", 4.2d);
    record4.PredictedMetrics.Add("metric2", 0.4d);
    record4.PredictionTimeStamp = currTime.AddMinutes(3);
    records.Add(record4);

    //What's the LINQ that could replace this method?
    GenerateSeperateMetricLists(records).Dump();  
}

private static List<List<PredictionObj>> GenerateSeperateMetricLists(List<Predictions> predictionRecords)
{
    var predictionMetricLists = new List<List<PredictionObj>>();
    foreach (Predictions forecastRecord in predictionRecords)
    {
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> prediction in forecastRecord.PredictedMetrics)
        {
            PredictionObj predictionMetric = new PredictionObj
            {
                PredictedMetricName = prediction.Key,
                PredictedMetricValue = prediction.Value,
                PredictionTimeStamp = forecastRecord.PredictionTimeStamp
            };
            var metricList = predictionMetricLists.Where(x => x.First().PredictedMetricName == prediction.Key);
            if (metricList.Count() == 0)
            {
                predictionMetricLists.Add(new List<PredictionObj> {predictionMetric});
            }
            else
            {
                metricList.First().Add(predictionMetric);
            }
        }
    }
    return predictionMetricLists;
}

private class Predictions
{
    public Dictionary<string, double> PredictedMetrics  { get; private set; }
    public DateTime PredictionTimeStamp  { get; set; }
    public Predictions()
    {
        PredictedMetrics = new Dictionary<string, double>();
    }
}

private class PredictionObj
{
    public string PredictedMetricName  { get; set; }
    public double PredictedMetricValue  { get; set; }
    public DateTime PredictionTimeStamp  { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? SO is not a code service site

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first flatten the data into a list of `PredictionObj`:

```
var flatList = records
    .SelectMany(r => r.PredictedMetrics.Select(p => new PredictionObj
        {
            PredictedMetricName = p.Key,
            PredictedMetricValue = p.Value,
            PredictionTimeStamp = r.PredictionTimeStamp
        }));
```

This produces a flat sequence of `PredictionObj` objects. Now you can group them by `PredictedMetricName`:

```
flatList.GroupBy(x => x.PredictedMetricName).Dump();
```

The query syntax equivalent, in one statement:

```
(
    from r in records
    from p in r.PredictedMetrics
    select new PredictionObj
    {
        PredictedMetricName = p.Key,
        PredictedMetricValue = p.Value,
        PredictionTimeStamp = r.PredictionTimeStamp
    } into flatList
    group flatList by flatList.PredictedMetricName into fg
    select fg
).Dump();
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to take each `Prediction` and project it into a `List<PredictionObj>` and then convert those into a `List<Prediction>`:

```
var ans = records.SelectMany(p => p.PredictedMetrics.Select(pm => new PredictionObj { PredictedMetricName = pm.Key, PredictedMetricValue = pm.Value, PredictionTimeStamp = p.PredictionTimeStamp }))
                 .GroupBy(p => p.PredictedMetricName)
                 .Select(g => g.ToList())
                 .ToList();
```

Updated for change in OP.

Comment: Please add some indentation.

Comment: Ugh, so sorry @NetMage, there was a typo in my question that I didn't notice until I tested your answer. I want a seperate list for each unique key, rather than each key value pair. I've updated my answer with a LINQPad script to make things clear. The object I call Dump() on is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Then my answer becomes similar to @GertArnold except I added a projection to create the `List<List<PredicitonObj>>`.